# NodeJS: How to redirect unauthenticated user to Microsoft login page using `passport-azure-ad`

Tags: node.js, passport.js, azure-ad-msal, passport-azure-ad

In my node/express app, I am trying to authenticate users using `passport-azure-ad` npm package, does anyone knows how can I redirect the user to the microsoft login screen? for example with the help of a route like following:

`app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) { passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer',`

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can create the middleware.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 if (req.session.user == null) // if user is not logged-in redirect back to login page 
 res.redirect('/');
 }   else{
  next();
 }
});
```

User OIDC Strategy to redirect the user to the Azure AD login form and get an id token on successful login. Use Bearer Strategy to validate an access token attached to a HTTP request.

Comment: Hello @Rutha thank you for the help, I thought this is auto handled by the library.

Comment: Also do you know how can we revoke access for a token ? Let's say the user authenticated successfully via his Microsoft account and received an access_token, when we disable the user's account in Microsoft then the user should not be able to use the API calls with the current access_token.